# htmlToFo Transformer (an XSL file which should have logic to copy even style attributes of HTML to FO)

Tags: html, xslt, xsl-fo, css-to-pdf

I am using javax.xml.transform.Transformer to transform XHTML to XSL-FO using an XSL parser. But the parser I have is not able to copy style attributes to XSL-FO.
So, can you help with valid parser which should be able to parse XHTML with style attributes to XSL-FO.

Comment: Copying style attribute from HTML to XSL FO will do nothing for you. There is no such attribute in XSL FO. You need an XSLT that processes style and writes out proper XSL FO equivalent structures.

Comment: @KevinBrown yes , need an XSLT that processes style and writes out proper XSL FO equivalent structures... any idea on stadard XSLT which can do this.

Comment: You should specify what XSL version you target.  2.0 and above would be somewhat trivial using tokenize() but 1.0 would require recursion.

Comment: Thanks for update @KevinBrown,

Yes, XSL version I am using is 2.0. Can you please share more info on tokenize() or any link where i can the info of tokenize()

Answer (score 1):

You can expand on this simple example, using a choose structure to eliminate/change the names to recognized XSL FO attributes. There are things in HTML like a style that starts-with "-moz" that likely has no meaning in XSL FO. Some others need adjustments made. You would also need to handle direct attributes (like `@colspan` or `@rowspan`) that are not in the `@style` attribute.

Given this simple input:

```
<p style="font-size:12pt; font-weight:bold; color: red">This is a sample</p>
```

Using this XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@style">
    <xsl:variable name="styleList" select="tokenize(.,';')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$styleList">
        <xsl:attribute name="{normalize-space(substring-before(.,':'))}">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(.,':'))"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You get this output:

```
<fo:block xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-size="12pt" font-weight="bold" color="red">This is a sample</fo:block
```

You can see the `tokenize()` function split the `@style` attribute into parts and those parts are used to create appropriate XSL FO attributes.

The site using similar methods is linked below. It has a very complex XSL for handling inline `@style` to XSL FO attributes.

[Cloudformatter CSStoPDF](http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf)